# How to do SharePoint 2016 Branding - Suite Nav Bar Changes?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, branding, suitebar

I'm attempting to update the Suite Nav Bar in SharePoint 2016 but running into issues.

1. How do I hide SuiteNavBrandingText?  I tried using PowerShell but the word "SharePoint" appears.

Ex.  $webapp.suitenavbrandingtext = "" shows "SharePoint" text.

I'm using "DEV" as a placeholder. Is there any CSS which I can use to hide this text?  See image.

2. I added a banner image to the Suite Nav Bar using $webapp.suitenavbrandinglogourl and manipulated height and width using .o365cs-base.o365cs-topnavBGColor-2.  However, the height spills into the browse and page bar. Please See the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could the below css style to hide the SuiteNavBrandingText. Add this to master page to deploy to all pages in the site.

```
<style>
.o365cs-nav-brandingText
{
     display: none !important;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code for SuiteNavBrandingText:

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication “http://ca.krossfarm.com”    
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingText = “Central Admin (Dev)”    
$webapp.Update()
```

To Set the Logo:

```
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoUrl = "http://ca.krossfarm.com1/Shared%20Documents/leaf-and-flames-logo.jpg"    
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle ="KrossFarm"    
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl = "http://ca.krossfarm.com"    
$webapp.Update()
```

Source: credit to this article:

[SharePoint 2016 How Change SuitBar’s Text PowerShell](https://krossfarm.com/?p=620)